# When you are free or whenever you're free

Tags: sentence-construction

Is it better to say in a professional email:

we can schedule a call when you are free
Or
We can schedule a call whenever you are free

What's the difference?

Answer (score 1):

"When you are free" suggests the next available free moment. For example, one might say "I'm busy now, I'll call you when I'm free", to mean that they will call when the busy period ends.

"Whenever you are free" is more open, inviting the person to select any free time in their schedule.